# How to redirect user to custom URL (view)?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-request, laravel-views

I have such URL in Laravel 5:

```
domain.com/search-user/email@domain.net
```

When I enter this URL, it automatically searches data by given email.

How I should redirect user from other controller to this URL?

I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
return view(‘controller.search-user')->with('email', $request->email);
```

My routes file:

```
Route::post('/search-user', 'tnt6weeklistController@postSearchUser');
Route::get('/search-user/{email}', 'tnt6weeklistController@postSearchUser');
```

-------SOLVED----------
Solved issue only with this code (maybe it is not the best practice, but other solutions didn't worked):

```
return \Redirect::to('http://domain.com/search-user/'.$request->email);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work.

```
return url('/search-user/' . urlencode($request->email));
```

Note that this changes `@` into `%40` ([see here](https://3v4l.org/sZcm3)), so you need to replace that in the place you handle this request.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively to what Loek answered you can set the arguments of the route using `redirect()->route()` method

Example:

```
return redirect()->route('search-user', ['email' =>  $request->email]);
```

Assuming that "email" is a proper route parameter.

More Details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redirects

Comment: Thank you, but i get such error: "InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [search-user] not defined." P.S i also included routes file info in primary topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the route for it then you can do something like this,

```
return \Redirect::route('search-user/example@email.com');
```

Comment: Thank you, but i get such error: "InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [search-user] not defined." Also i have tryed this one: return \Redirect::route('tnt6week-list.search-user')->with('email', $request->email); But same error.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked you whether you have a route for it or not? So how do you go to that view then?

Comment: Looking at your routes I can see that you have passed {email} in the route. so your redirect will look something like this, Redirect::route('search-user/asd@asd.com'); or similar. I also edited my answer

Comment: Thank you, but still having problems. My code: `return \Redirect::route('tnt6week-list.search-user/'.$request->email);` And i still get error: `InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [tnt6week-list.search-user/email@domain.net] not defined.`

Comment: With all due respect, but RTFM. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes ==> `Route::get( ... )->name('search-user');`

Comment: I would'nt post a question here, if i know how to achieve. Non of the answers are working. Maybe issue is somewhere else. I have read enough before posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using $_GET for this, so instead of having the url as you have it, do this instead:

domain.com/search-user/?email=email@domain.net

And change your code so that you're processing `$_GET['email']`. This should help with the redirect problem.